# Tkinter Python 3.3.2 calculator

Tags: tkinter

Calculator python
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an instance of a tkinter [Label](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#label) widget for the display, and a group of tkinter [Button](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#button) widgets for the buttons. Use the [grid geometry manager](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) to organize them on the screen. You can associate each button with a command that will either add a number to an internal register, or perform a calculation on the number(s) in the register.

Start by working through a [tkinter tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) to understand the basics, and that should give you more than enough information to create a calculator since you only need a couple of fundamental widget types.